# Storing File to public storage of Laravel (ReactJS & Laravel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I start doing CMS using Laravel and ReactJS. this is my first time to use this. I have problem regarding storing file to the public storage of laravel. I know this is duplicate question. but i need to solve this. Thanks.

1. I start testing inserting content w/ out file. the output is (Success)
2. **This is my problem when i start doing storing file to public storage it gives me error.**

**My input file:**

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
```

[image: Image error]

This is my function in my Controller:

```
public function save_home_content(Request $request)
{

    $content_page = $request->get('pageValue');
    $content_section = $request->get('sectionValue');
    $content_title = $request->get('titleValue');
    $content = $request->get('textValue');
    $content_link = $request->get('linkValue');

    $now = new DateTime();

    if($request->get('imageValue'))
    {
        $file = $request->get('imageValue');
        $content_type = $request->get('typeValue');


        $filename =  $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        return $request->storeAs('public',$filename);

       try {

       }
       catch(\Exception $e)
       {
        return $e->getMessage();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check storage/logs/laravel.log for more info?

are you sure that the path is writeable by the server?

Comment: i found the problem but still not working to it.. return $file = Input::file('image'); i use this. it happens no file found.

Comment: @BogdanCismariu based on my response.console  that my data = "" only

Comment: Are you sure you are uploading the file? Please consult https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#files for details on how to check if the file exists and if the file is valid.

Comment: @DevGe

Have you done  enctype="multipart/form-data" in form

Comment: yes in form i have this. <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">

Comment: May Be this video help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeiOnkEI7XI

Comment: based to laravel documents hasFile it says . {data: "No File Input", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Answer (score 2):

**step 1 :**

first create folder inside **/storage/app/public** directory  :

/storage/app/public/**uploads**  <-- inside upload folder , you will save your images

**step 2 :**

- give 777 permission to storage folder
- run `php artisan storage:link` command in terminal (this will make symlink of your `/storage` folder contents inside `projectname/public/storage/` )

**step 3 :**

inside your controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function upload(Request $request){
      $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:10000'
        ]);

        if ($validation->fails()){
            $response=array('status'=>'error','errors'=>$validation->errors()->toArray());  
            return response()->json($response);
        }

     if($request->hasFile('image')){

        $uniqueid=uniqid();
        $original_name=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName(); 
        $size=$request->file('image')->getSize();
        $extension=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $name=$uniqueid.'.'.$extension;
        $path=$request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads',$name);
        if($path){
            return response()->json(array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Image successfully uploaded','image'=>'/storage/uploads/'.$name));
        }else{
            return response()->json(array('status'=>'error','message'=>'failed to upload image'));
        }
    }

}
```

**step 4 :**

your react component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      const fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileupload') ;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', fileInput.files[0]);

      fetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: formData
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
      })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <form method="POST" id="upload-image"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
          <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="image" required/>
          <button type="submit" id="btnUploadFile">Upload File</button>
       </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**step 5 :**

you can access images using path => `yourdomain.com/storage/uploads/imagename.jpg`

in blade.php you can access using `<img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/imagename.jpg')}}"/>`

Comment: hi.. question. is it okay to use only the folder of public to store image. without creating new folder?

Comment: yes it is ok , use `request()->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileNameToStore);` if you want to direct save inside public folder , but as you are using laravel , you should use Storage ...it is recomanded way , read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Comment: @DevGe, also add `csrf-token` in header in fetch method

Comment: i have error for getclientOriginal Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: i think your file is not passing to server , so you get this error

Comment: try to `dd($request->file('file'));`

Comment: quest saurabh.. $request->file('is this the name of file?'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181728/discussion-between-devge-and-saurabh-mistry).

Comment: `<input type='file" name="image"` />` .  then check `$request->input('image')`

Comment: @DevGe , any progress ?

Comment: sorry on last previous i'm off duty.. probably i check the file that i input. the server says no file found.